# Storing a C struct in CFMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-foundation

Since there is no counterpart to NSValue in Core Foundation, how are we supposed to store C structs in a CFMutableDictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you can put an NSvalue in a CFMutableDictionary as-is, so the answer is "use NSValue." But I assume the rest of your question is "without using any Cocoa objects." In that case, just create a non-retaining CFMutableDictionary, and you can put any pointer you want into it. See ["Defining Custom Collection Callbacks"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001132-101215-CHDEBBDB) for some example code. I use these a lot.

Remember that these still have to be pointers, so you're going to have to allocate your structs on the heap, not the stack. And that means that memory management is now your problem. Of course you could create a custom set of callbacks that do whatever you want, so if you're using boost or something else with its own ref-counting system, you can still implement that with CFMutableDictionary.

And of course you can replace the struct with a small data object. That's usually a lot easier. But different problems need different solutions.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Exactly what I was looking for: Non-retaining dictionary.

Comment: Another option would be passing the structs via a CFData object. The API isn't quite tailored to this sort of usage, and you'd lose the endian-awareness aspects that NSValue provides, but I don't see many other drawbacks. In a sense, NSValue and NSData both store a copy of "raw bytes". NSValue just tracks some extra metadata, which for many purposes — i.e. passing structs around in memory via CF collection classes — is probably unnecessary. So instead of adding your value type as a category on NSValue, you could write some helper functions to/from CFDataRef instead?

Answer (score 1):

CFMutableDictionary

CFDictionaryAddValue
A CFType object or a pointer value to add to the dictionary.

you just pass a pointer to your struct.

Comment: Wow I definitely should have looked a bit closer at the documents. Do I have to supply a custom callback or can I just use it as is?

Comment: This will crash when the pointer to the struct is handed to the default retain method, which expects a CFType. You have to overload the callbacks in order for this to work.