# NSMutableDictionary for huge dataset of floats

Tags: objective-c, c, performance, hashmap, nsmutabledictionary

I've got some code to convert a large (many gigabytes) XML file into another format.

Among other things, I need to store one or two gigabytes of floats in a hash table (two floats for each entry), with an int as the value's key.

Currently, I'm using NSMutableDictionary and a custom class containing the two floats:

```
// create the dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *points = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// add an entry (the data is read from an XML file using libxml)
int pointId = 213453;
float x = 42.313554; 
float y = -21.135213; 

MyPoint *point = [[MyPoint alloc] initWithX:x Y:y];
[points setObject:point forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:pointId]];
[point release];

// retrieve an entry (this happens later on while parsing the same XML file)
int pointId = 213453;
float x;
float y;
MyPoint *point = [points objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:pointId]];
x = point.x;
y = point.y;
```

This data set is consuming about 800MB of RAM with the XML file I'm working with now, and it takes quite a long time to execute. I'd like to have better performance, but even more important I need to get the memory consumption down so I can process even larger XML files.

objc_msg_send is right up there in a profile of the code, as is `- [NSNumber numberWithInt:]`, and I'm sure I can get the memory usage down by avoiding objects altogether, but I don't know much about C programming (this project is certainly teaching me!).

How can I replace `NSMuableDictionary`, `NSNumber` `MyPoint` with an efficient C data structure? Without any third party library dependencies?

I'd also like to be able to write this data structure to files on the disk, so I can work with a dataset that doesn't entirely fit into memory, but I can probably live without this capability.

*(for those not familiar with Objective-C, the NSMutableDictionary class can only store Obj-C objects, and it the keys must also be objects. NSNumber and MyPoint are dumb container classes to allow NSMutableDictionary to work with float and int values.)*

***EDIT:***

I've tried using CFMutableDictionary to store structs, as per [apple's sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFCollections/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001132-101215-CHDEBBDB). When the dictionary is empty, it performs great. But as the dictionary grows it gets slower and slower. About 25% through parsing a file (~4 million items in the dictionary) it starts to chug, two orders of magnitude slower than earlier in the file.

NSMutableDictionary doesn't have the same performance issue. Instruments shows a lot of activity applying hashes and comparing the keys of the dictionary (the `intEqual()` method below). Comparing an int is fast, so something is very wrong for it to be executing so often.

Here's my code to create the dictionary:

```
typedef struct {
  float lat;
  float lon;
} AGPrimitiveCoord;

void agPrimitveCoordRelease(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void *ptr) {
    CFAllocatorDeallocate(allocator, (AGPrimitiveCoord *)ptr);
}

Boolean agPrimitveCoordEqual(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2) {
    AGPrimitiveCoord *p1 = (AGPrimitiveCoord *)ptr1;
    AGPrimitiveCoord *p2 = (AGPrimitiveCoord *)ptr2;

    return (fabsf(p1->lat - p2->lat) < 0.0000001 && fabsf(p1->lon - p2->lon) < 0.0000001);

}

Boolean intEqual(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2) {
    return (int)ptr1 == (int)ptr2;
}

CFHashCode intHash(const void *ptr) {
  return (CFHashCode)((int)ptr);
}

// init storage dictionary
CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks intKeyCallBacks = {0, NULL, NULL, NULL, intEqual, intHash};
CFDictionaryValueCallBacks agPrimitveCoordValueCallBacks = {0, NULL /*agPrimitveCoordRetain*/, agPrimitveCoordRelease, NULL, agPrimitveCoordEqual};
temporaryNodeStore = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &intKeyCallBacks, &agPrimitveCoordValueCallBacks);

// add an item to the dictionary
- (void)parserRecordNode:(int)nodeId lat:(float)lat lon:(float)lon
{
  AGPrimitiveCoord *coordPtr = (AGPrimitiveCoord *)CFAllocatorAllocate(NULL, sizeof(AGPrimitiveCoord), 0);
  coordPtr->lat = lat;
  coordPtr->lon = lon;

  CFDictionarySetValue(temporaryNodeStore, (void *)nodeId, coordPtr);
}
```

***EDIT 2:***

The performance problem was due to the almost useless hashing implementation in Apple's sample code. I got the performance way up by using this:

```
// hash algorithm from http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/integer.html
uint32_t a = abs((int)ptr);
a = (a+0x7ed55d16) + (a<<12);
a = (a^0xc761c23c) ^ (a>>19);
a = (a+0x165667b1) + (a<<5);
a = (a+0xd3a2646c) ^ (a<<9);
a = (a+0xfd7046c5) + (a<<3);
a = (a^0xb55a4f09) ^ (a>>16);
```

Comment: Will this file ever change after deployment? I'm thinking about preprocessing.

Comment: I will never be using this code in deployment. It's a command line tool which creates a database that is deployed along with my app (I'm extracting a few hundred megabytes from openstreetmap.org's ~300GB dataset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want NSMutableDictionary-like behavior but with malloc'd memory, you can drop down to [CFDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/) (or in your case, [CFMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html)). It's actually the underpinnings of NSMutableDictionary, but it allows some customization, namely you can tell it that you're not storing objects. When you call `CFDictionaryCreateMutable()` you give it a struct that describes what sort of values you're handing it (it contains pointers that tell it how to retain, release, describe, hash, and compare your values). So if you want to use a struct containing two floats, and you're happy using malloc'd memory for each struct, you can malloc your struct, populate it, and hand that to the `CFDictionary`, and then you can write the callback functions such that they work with your particular struct. The only restriction on the keys and objects you can use `CFDictionary` with is they need to fit inside a `void *`.

Comment: I believe using `CFDictionaryCreate` might be faster because the method receives all keys and values at once, hence the internal implementation might only have to allocate memory once for all records.

Comment: @tia: If you never have to mutate your dictionary, then sure, go ahead and use `CFDictionaryCreate()`. It'll be faster to create (since as you say it won't have to grow the dictionary over time), and it's possible that it may be faster to access (e.g. the mutable version may use a less efficient structure under-the-hood, but that's not necessarily true and would be an implementation detail anyway).

Comment: So I'm following the example code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203726/storing-a-c-struct-in-cfmutabledictionary and performance is unacceptable. When the dictionary is almost empty, It adds about 65000 entries per second. When the dictionary contains 4 million rows, it's only adding 600 items per second. NSMutableDictionary is a *lot* faster than that, any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty much using exactly Apple's sample code linked in the above question's accepted answer, and will edit my question to include my code.

Comment: @tia `CFDictionaryCreate` will create an empty dictionary. I need to add 20 million items to it as I parse an XML file, with no way of even knowing how many I need to add until after I've finished parsing it. So NS/CFMutableDictionary is the only option.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Maybe you need a better hash function?

Comment: @KevinBallard I thought it might be that, but figured i should trust apple's sample code. Clearly not. I got performance up to around 100,000 inserts per second by using the second hash implementation on this page: http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/integer.html

Comment: I wrote a code for test here http://snipt.org/wmsn5 to show that CFDictionaryCreate is pretty fast if you can manage to get all keys and values in const void** array first. I also wrote the test for reallocating the array buffer to simulate the situation that we don't know the number of all records beforehand. Hope this help.

Comment: @tia how do you think that would compare, performance wise, to simply using NSMutableDictionary? Remember, I am inserting into each key exactly once, later reading each key at most once (a small percentage of the data is never used), and then I'm deallocating the whole data set.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert The performance of inserting key/value one by one should be more or less the same as sorting hash with insertion sort, which is O(n^2). When the current dictionary grows bigger, time used for inserting will increase exponentially. If you give the dictionary the whole set of keys/values at once, the implementation can sort the keys with faster sorting algorithm, hence the performance gain and I did the test as evidence of that.

Answer (score 3):

For this sort of thing I would just use C++ containers `std::unordered_map` and `std::pair`.  You can use them in Objective-C++.  Just give your files a `.mm` extension instead of the usual `.m` extension.

### Update

In your comment you said you've never done C++ before.  In that case, you should either try Kevin Ballard's answer of `CFDictionary`, or check out the `hcreate`, `hdestroy`, and `hsearch` functions in the standard library.

[`hcreate` man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/hcreate.3.html)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to define an unordered map, add an entry to it, and remove one? I've never written even a single line of C++. What type of performance should I expect when randomly accessing values from a several hundred meg data set?

Comment: Thanks. I looked into it, but couldn't get my head around the man page. CFMutableDictionary is working great.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your .m file to .mm and switch to using C++:

```
std::map<int, std::pair<float>> points;
```